# Accessing properties of another object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I am working on CRM app as a demo project. Currently I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around how to access properties of one object from another. I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
 <%= note.client.first_name %>
```

In this case, I have a note for each client and the appropriate association set up between the two. The models look like so:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :user
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :notes
end
```

And the databases look like so:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :last_name
    t.string :designation
    t.string :phone
    t.string :email
    t.string :password_digest

    t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any easy way of accessing the :first_name property of the client id associated with the note?

Comment: associated with the :users or :note ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `delegate` method:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :first_name, to: :client
end
```

then in your view you can access the delegated property from the object to which it was delegated:

```
<%= note.first_name %>
```

Comment: I think the generated method should be `client_first_name`?

Comment: Only if the method is called with the `prefix: true` option.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I personally prefer `prefix: true` option.

Comment: Any particular reason (other than preference) why you would just the prefix option over delegates to?